# Java Programming, Adding Labels & Totals to Table

Tags: java, arrays, label

Working on big program, that reads from a file and prints to another. It seems to print out fine, but we need labels. Our program prints like this:

```
40851   50497   813082  1118366 1120629 
34400   45547   824439  1425116 1429306 
39249   48833   809627  1101561 1103908 
57939   67308   821564  1126250 1128620 
64000   76037   827086  1424632 1431210 
34200   40240   554391  767810  772107  
89310   101149  2351871 2971044 2980458 
84370   95851   2470295 3096137 3105516 
59700   71190   2290032 2905223 2909869 
67600   79212   2419095 3031704 3034002 
60200   71594   2348818 2969848 2972035 
46000   56050   824092  1300904 1303163
```

We need it to print out the totals and labels like this (ignore the numbers):

[image]

Here is our code:

```
package hotelreport;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HotelReport {

    static File hotelFile = new File("store.txt");
    static Path outputFilePath = Paths.get("storeAnswer.txt");
    static int  invoiceID;
    static int serviceCode;
    static String invoiceDate;
    static double saleAmount;
    static int rows = 13;
    static int columns = 6;
    static int[][] table;

    public static void main(String[]args){

            getData();
            PrintWriter out;
            File file = new File("storeAnswer.txt");

            try {
                out = new PrintWriter("storeAnswer.txt");
                for(int i =0;i<=11;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<=4;j++){
                        out.print(table[i][j]);
                        out.print("\t");
                    }
                    out.println("");
                }
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found");
            }



    }

    public static void getData(){
        table = new int[rows][columns];

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(hotelFile);

            while(sc.hasNext()){
                invoiceID = sc.nextInt();
                serviceCode = sc.nextInt();
                String invoiceDate = sc.next();
                saleAmount = sc.nextDouble();
                switch(serviceCode){
                    case 0: 
                        if(invoiceDate.startsWith("01")){
                            table[0][0]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("02")){
                            table[1][0]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("03")){
                            table[2][0]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("04")){
                            table[3][0]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("05")){
                            table[4][0]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("06")){
                            table[5][0]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("07")){
                            table[6][0]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("08")){
                            table[7][0]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("09")){
                            table[8][0]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("10")){
                            table[9][0]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("11")){
                            table[10][0]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("12")){
                            table[11][0]+=saleAmount;
                        };
                    case 1:
                        if(invoiceDate.startsWith("01")){
                            table[0][1]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("02")){
                            table[1][1]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("03")){
                            table[2][1]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("04")){
                            table[3][1]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("05")){
                            table[4][1]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("06")){
                            table[5][1]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("07")){
                            table[6][1]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("08")){
                            table[7][1]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("09")){
                            table[8][1]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("10")){
                            table[9][1]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("11")){
                            table[10][1]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("12")){
                            table[11][1]+=saleAmount;
                        };
                    case 2:
                        if(invoiceDate.startsWith("01")){
                            table[0][2]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("02")){
                            table[1][2]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("03")){
                            table[2][2]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("04")){
                            table[3][2]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("05")){
                            table[4][2]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("06")){
                            table[5][2]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("07")){
                            table[6][2]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("08")){
                            table[7][2]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("09")){
                            table[8][2]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("10")){
                            table[9][2]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("11")){
                            table[10][2]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("12")){
                            table[11][2]+=saleAmount;
                        };
                    case 3:
                        if(invoiceDate.startsWith("01")){
                            table[0][3]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("02")){
                            table[1][3]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("03")){
                            table[2][3]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("04")){
                            table[3][3]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("05")){
                            table[4][3]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("06")){
                            table[5][3]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("07")){
                            table[6][3]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("08")){
                            table[7][3]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("09")){
                            table[8][3]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("10")){
                            table[9][3]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("11")){
                            table[10][3]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("12")){
                            table[11][3]+=saleAmount;
                        };
                    case 4:
                        if(invoiceDate.startsWith("01")){
                            table[0][4]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("02")){
                            table[1][4]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("03")){
                            table[2][4]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("04")){
                            table[3][4]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("05")){
                            table[4][4]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("06")){
                            table[5][4]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("07")){
                            table[6][4]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("08")){
                            table[7][4]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("09")){
                            table[8][4]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("10")){
                            table[9][4]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("11")){
                            table[10][4]+=saleAmount;
                        }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("12")){
                            table[11][4]+=saleAmount;
                        };


                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found. Check Location");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("File coud not be created");
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Your code has much unnecessary redundancy; you can simplify the code a *lot*, and in the process make it much easier for you to debug and for us to read and understand.

Comment: And what's the question?  Because right now the only obvious problem is that the code to do the required formatting is missing...

Comment: You should use `Integer.parseInt(...)` to parse `invoiceDate.substring(0, 2)` massage that number and then use it to reduce your code by 90% or more.

Answer (score 1):

You would just change what you print out with each value whenever you call your print command (out.print)

Unrelated, but if you're doing:

```
                    if(invoiceDate.startsWith("01")){
                        table[0][0]+=saleAmount;
                    }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("02")){
                        table[1][0]+=saleAmount;
                    }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("03")){
                        table[2][0]+=saleAmount;
                    }else if(invoiceDate.startsWith("04")){
                        table[3][0]+=saleAmount;
                    }else ...
```

Why not just use a loop?:

```
for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
    if (invoiceDate.startsWith("0" + (i + 1)) {
        table[i][0]+=saleAmount;
    }
}
```

Of course, there can still be even more improvements to be had, but that would at least be a start.

EDIT:

Ahh, now that you add the table it makes a bit more sense. You would most likely want to add the month after the loop for data (where you print the new line), and have an initial print of the column values.